# Entrywise operations between Julia arrays of booleans

Tags: julia

I would like to create an array whose entries are `true` when the corresponding entry in `arr1` is `true` and the corresponding entry in `arr2` is false. I can do this arithmetically:

```
arr1 = [true false true
    true true false]

arr2 = [true false false
    true false true]

# Arithmetic way
convert(Array{Bool}, (arr1 .* (1 .- arr2)))
```

But I find the following more readable:

```
# Intuitive way (doesn't work)
arr1 .& !arr2
```

Is there a working Julia syntax that looks more like this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
arr1 .& .!arr2
```

yields

```
2×3 BitArray{2}:
 0  0  1
 0  1  0
```

Comment: or `@. arr1 & !arr2`